# Low cost low speed fiber optic connection for embedded applications

Tags: microcontroller, communication, optoelectronics, optical-fibre

I would like to use a fiber connection to send data between two nodes. The nodes would typically have a 8 or 32 bit micro controller. I need data rate of 2 Mbps or higher and distance is about 100 meters. What are some cost effective ways of achieving this? Can full duplex communication be achieved with single fiber as is the case with fiber from various ISPs?

Comment: This feels like a shopping question, however there are quite a few resources online: [#1](https://www.digikey.ca/en/articles/techzone/2014/jun/microcontrollers-and-fiber-optics), [#2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.electronics.design/IIZRYKhGlYQ), [#3](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slat138/slat138.pdf).

Comment: You probably want to look at "industrial fiber optics" possibly using plastic optical fiber (POF) although 100 m might be a bit long for POF.

Comment: Happen to be at the digikey site POF 250m = $411 with 200dB/KM I have no idea how easy it is to splice POF yourself...

Comment: I know every little about this but my gut feeling is that electrical transport might be simpler, cheaper and just as reliable.  Why not ask: what electrical protocol/system lets me transport 2Mbs over 100m.

Comment: Are you worried that cable comms cannot easily hack 100 metres at that snail rate of 2 Mbps? XY problem?

Comment: Where are these nodes? Why not wireless?

Comment: @oldfart Broadcom has several different POF types (listed [here](https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/AV00-0269EN)) including one with "only" 160 dB/km attenuation. But none of their POF transmit/receive solutions promises 1 Mbps at 100 m, so this application might need glass fiber. They do have many options with "hard clad silica" fiber.

Comment: @oldfart I am aware of other technologies. But I *want* to use fiber.